# How can I ping to a nested AP's client

Tags: networking, routes, raspberry-pi, ping

Basically I have a home route that throw dhcp via wifi 192.168.1.0/24 and my Raspberr pi-1 is connected to router with ip 192.168.1.119 via wlan0. I have set pi-1 as another AP so it throw dhcp of network 127.24.1.0/24. now i want to ping between

PC with ip 192.168.1.25 to another pi-2 connected in pi-1 (172.24.1.15) AP through wifi.
how can i do this plzzz help me here. and also i have internet connection in all devices but cannot ping why?

Comment: [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) works one way - you just have no way to reach inside of LAN from outside due to NAT's nature. You can reconfigure RPI to use bridge mode. this way there will be no nested network and seconf pi will get address from your router.

Comment: thanks for your answer @MaximSagaydachny. Can i do this by multicast from pc (192.168.1.25)  and forward that data via pi 1 to pi 2 by setting up firewall rule (ie iptables)? at this point i just want to send data